# D: What difference between map and each?

Tags: iteration, d

std.algorithm have two function for iteration `map` and `each`. I can't understand what is the difference?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`each` performs an eager evaluation, while `map` performs a lazy one.
This means that when you apply `each`, every element is calculated immediately, while `map` calculates its results only when you access them.

This also means that `each` is unsuitable for infinite streams.

Answer (score 6):

`map` isn't for iteration, it is a transforming function. (Indeed, applying map to a range doesn't iterate over it at all; "evaluation is done lazily" in its docs mean you are still responsible for iterating over the result yourself.)

`each` is a variant of `map` that does do the iteration automatically, while transforming in the process. It also works on the `opApply` style of iteration, whereas `map` doesn't.

http://dlang.org/phobos/std_algorithm_iteration.html#.each

http://dlang.org/phobos/std_algorithm_iteration.html#.map

`each` is something you'd do at the end of a series of transformations, when you are ready to process the result and possibly save the changes back to the original range (`each` can save changes in-place, whereas `map` just returns the changes). `map` is an intermediate tool.

Answer (score 5):

`map` takes a range and applies a function to every element in the range, and returns a range with the results. The range is *lazily evaluated*, so you wont compute any values unless you do something else with the range, like apply `foreach` to it.

`each` applies a function to every element in a range *eagerly*. So `each` is like a one-line `foreach`.

```
// Do some pointless application of map.
// The map won't be run here.
auto range = iota(0, 10).map!(x => cast(float) x);

// Now write all of them to stdout.
// This will be evaluated.
range.each!writeln;
```

Comment: Could you show me how to rewrite next code with each?
```foreach(ArchiveMember am; zip.directory)
writeln(am.name);```

Comment: `zip.directory.each!(am => writeln(am.name))`

or

`zip.directory.map!(am => am.name).each!writeln`.

Supposing `directory` is a range. If not, you'll have to get a range from it somehow.

Comment: Using predicates with side effects (like I/O) with `map` is allowed but not guaranteed to work in general - it is an idiom designed for functional programming style.

Comment: Could you give me link where I can read about what is predicates. I googled it but still not fully understand what it is. Or if you can, you can explain it's here. I would be very pleased.

Comment: w0rp, both variants do not work. second even do not compile. First print ```std.zip.ArchiveMember``` on console.

How I can understand what type have ```directory```?

Comment: @Suliman The documentation for `std.zip` says it's an associative array. http://dlang.org/phobos/std_zip.html#.ZipArchive The type is  `ArchiveMember[string]`. So you need to use a range over the associative array to use algorithms with it. `zip.directory.byValue.each!(am => wrilten(am.name)` would work, but the keys have the names anyway, so you can use `zip.directory.byKey.each!writeln` in this case.